# How to set variable to blank when no check boxes are checked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on an assignment where i have to take a users preferences and match them with a suitable mobile phone contract. If the users doesn't select a check box i want to display all the contracts, though i am struggling to do this.

This is the code i have so far:

```
    //Check Network
var userNetwork;
var networkForm=document.getElementById("NN");
var networkForm=document.getElementById("Othree");
var networkForm=document.getElementById("Fodavone");
var networkForm=document.getElementById("ZMobile");
if(NN.checked){
    userNetwork="NN";
}
if(Othree.checked){
    userNetwork="03";
}
if(Fodavone.checked){
    userNetwork="Fodavone";
}
if(ZMobile.checked){
    userNetwork="Z-Mobile";
}


for (var c = 0; c < cont.length; c++) {
    if (userNetwork === cont[c].network || userNetwork === "") {
```

I think i need to add some code to the end of the check network if statement , though im not sure what. Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but the repeated assignment to `networkForm` is clearly a mistake here. Is it your first time with programming? It might be worth to take a look at some of the [variable basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). What happens if you replace `networkForm` on each line to the word inside the quotes? Example: `var NN = document.getElementById("NN");`

Comment: Initialize the variable to empty string `var userNetwork = ""` to check if it is empty just run `userNetwork == ""` in your if. At least that's how I understood the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a default value :

```
var userNetwork = ''; // could alternatively be any default value
```

Then update your for loop to check for match for '':

```
for (var c = 0; c < cont.length; c++) {
    if (userNetwork === cont[c].network || userNetwork === "") {
```

The main issue is that you never initialize `userNetwork` so `userNetwork === ""` doesn't match since there isn't a value. You could alternatively leave your variable `userNetwork` undefined and change your check to be:

```
if (userNetwork === cont[c].network || userNetwork == null) {
```

You also may wish to change your checkboxes to radio as a user might select multiple carriers, depending on how your UI looks.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how i managed to overlook that, simple solution. As for switching them to radio buttons, i wanted to next make it so that users can select as many carries as they like and it will output any contracts with those providers, though i need to figure out how to do that first.

Comment: create a collection for the user network and then you can iterate over their list.